# How to send the value of a checkbox input instead of the boolean in ASP NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I have a .cshtml view like this:

```
<form asp-controller="X" asp-action="Y">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SomeListOfStrings.Count; i++)
    {
       <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.SomeListOfStrings[i]" />
    }
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I want to send the `value` of this `<input type="checkbox" value="@Model.SomeListOfStrings[i]" />` instead of the boolean in my request (and only if the checkbox is checked). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this in your cshtml:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SomeListOfStrings.Count; i++)
     {
         <input name="AreChecked" type="checkbox" value="@Model.SomeListOfStrings[i]" /> @Model.SomeListOfStrings[i]
         <br />
     }
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Give your input's the same name - `AreChecked` in this example.  Set the `value` to your strings in your collection as you are already.

Then, in your controller method, add a `List<string>` parameter called `AreChecked` or whatever you named it, and that should automatically bind the checked items and have their values upon submitting:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(List<string> AreChecked)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Example view:

[image: view showing 3 checkboxes]

If I check the "hi" and "hello" checkboxes, when I submit the form, the controller's parameter is bound with those values:

[image: controller parameter list showing checked items values]

I referenced [this page](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes#simple-collections) to do this if you want more information.